# How to get a discord bot to undeafen them self when it join a voice channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to have my bot play some music from a link we have we are able to have the bot join the voice channel but it joins already deafened so it will not play the sounds we need.

How would I get the bot to be able to join and undeafen itself?

```js
require('dotenv').config(); //initialize dotenv
require('discord-reply');
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildBans,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers
    ] });
const {
    token,
    voicechannel,
    list
} = require('./config.json');

const { 
    joinVoiceChannel, 
    getVoiceConnection,
    createAudioPlayer,
    createAudioResource

} = require('@discordjs/voice');


const voice = require('@discordjs/voice');
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
message.content.startsWith('!activetest')) {
//cha and gui is a const i have somewhere else, it will define the channel id and the guild id
        const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
            channelId: cha,
            guildId: gui,
            adapterCreator: client.guilds.cache.get("1080859608257671338").voiceAdapterCreator,
        });
}
});
```

With the code above the bot will join the channel when asked to, how would I then have him unmute himself from that channel. I have tried a few different ways but none would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `selfDeaf` option to `false` when your bot joins the voice channel. I think this is what you're looking for:

```js
const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
  channelId: cha,
  guildId: gui,
  adapterCreator: client.guilds.cache.get('1080859608257671338')
    .voiceAdapterCreator,
  selfDeaf: false,
});
```